# Is there Android Intent concept in iPhone SDK

Tags: android, ios, iphone

Just switching from Android to iPhone. In Android I can make several apps and use a tabView to call each app as intent.

In iPhone, I can make several apps. I need a tab to call each apps or app views. Is there similar concept as intent in iPhone? Just switched to iPhone, copying all the other projects into the tabbar does not work out. If you have other methods to solve, I really appreciate. Thanks,

Answer (score 27):

Android and iOS are very different in this regard. Android is very open about letting you use intents to mix and match activities from other apps. iOS isn't like that; each app runs in its own private space and generally cannot even see other apps' data, let alone use their services. It *is* possible to cause other apps to run via custom URLs, but that's not the same thing.

What you'll need to do is to copy or move the code for the view controllers, views, etc. of your various iOS apps into your tab bar app project. You'll build them all into a single application, and the tab bar will switch between the view controllers.

Answer (score 18):

With iOS 8 you will have something similar to Android Intents. Using [App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html) you can reach similar behavior.

In a close future Apps will start expose their "extension" (as you do in Android Framework declaring Intent Filters in the manifest) that will be used by application who need.The extension areas allowed in this first version are:

- Today
- Share
- Action
- Foto Editing
- Document Provider
- Custom Keyboard

It's great finally apple release this functionality!

Answer (score 13):

Intent in Android covers a lot of functions. There is no iOS equivalent to that.

But if your objective is to launch a different app, and pass parameters to it, you can try out URL Schema.

Let's say you have app AAA with URL schema aaa:// and app BBB with URL bbb://
You can launch app AAA, and call bbb://v=1&c=2 for example, to launch BBB and get the parameters. you can even take these parameters to control what view to show, so you can have a similar concept in Android, to call different Activity with Intents.

You have to register URL schema in Info.plist

Comment: Could you add more info on how to register the protocol to the info.list? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The closest concept to an Intent on iOS is the handling of certain URLs by the system applications. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007891-SW1). It was possible to register your own application URL schemes at one point (see [this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) article), but I must admit I haven't tried this in recent **SDKs** (IIRC Glympse links can be opened in the Glympse app, so this technique probably still works).

Answer (score 4):

As of 2016, Apple has added an Intents framework that is similar to Android's, albeit much more restrictive. Expect Apple to add more Intents in the future, but for now it is quite limited. https://developer.apple.com/reference/intents

Comment: the iOS intents frameworks seems to center around Siri, i.e. accepting invocation from Siri and Maps. Does it work with ordinary app sharing feature?

Comment: @Thomas not currently, but it's clearly designed to be expanded in such a way in the future

Comment: Apple's Intents framework is not even close nor similar to Android's Intents

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 8, you can use [App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html).