# Flex mobile, opening external files

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile

Can I import files from other apps into my app? If I for instance on iOS, I email myself a xml-file, I click the attachment in the mail-app. Now I want the "open in" option to show up, send that file to my app, and process that data there. Is this possible in flex/as3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android uses the concept of intents to allow this type of thing; iOS does not have an equivalent. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630874/is-there-android-intent-concept-in-iphone-sdk) for more info.

Currently there is no way to map intents in android using flex/as3 without a [java wrapper](http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/) or ANE (native extension)