# Flex mobile communcation between flex apps vs native mobile apps

Tags: android, objective-c, ios, apache-flex, flex-mobile

I want to send from my Flex mobile app some string data to another application and launch the last one at the same time? Is this possible using Flex SDK (for both Android and iOS)?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

P.S I assumed there's some method of doing the same thing in native mobile development

UPDATE: I've done this using network according to this tutorial: http://blog.leeburrows.com/2011/10/p2p-flash-on-a-local-network-part1/

Any other "command line" like approaches would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To start an app from another app please check this answer on Stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10493320/1069487

Not sure if it is possible to pass start parameters (your String), a simple workaround would be a locally shared file.

Comment: How is the Android ANE not real time? And what listeners are you referring to? Plus, you'll have a hard time not using any event listeners in a Flex (or any AS3) application, mobile or not. There's noting wrong with them as long as you know how and when to use them.

Comment: As I said, that was just a simple workaround (that would definitely work, be easy to implement and does not cost any performance whatsoever) in case you cannot find a proper solution to pass parameters to an app.