# Add React-native app to 'Activities' panel on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I am looking for informations about to add an App in the 'Activities' IOS panel in order to can add my app to the list of sharing apps.

[image: a busy cat]

I don't know if it's automatic or if it need some configuration.

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but this question seems to have the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630874/is-there-android-intent-concept-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: And for react native, this is an example of how to do it - https://codeburst.io/building-a-mobile-share-extension-for-a-react-native-app-bff4ef91d44f

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using [AppExtensions in iOS SDK](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1).

In React native, the docs talk about App extensions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/app-extensions). And an example app for sharing is available in a [github repo](https://github.com/andrewsardone/react-native-ios-share-extension).

Comment: Thank you @vijayst ! i willl look at this